# How to create a new column based on certain values in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For each day, I have different colors which are used. I need to create a new column which looks at the ratio of users to  the first day for each color.

For example, for color blue, the earliest date is `2020-01-01` and the corresponding 'users' value is 100. So, for `2020-01-02`, the value I want should be `102/100 = 1.02`

```
raw_data = [
        {'date': '2020-01-01', 'color': 'blue', 'users': 100},
        {'date': '2020-01-02', 'color': 'blue', 'users': 102},
        {'date': '2020-01-03', 'color': 'blue', 'users': 104},
        {'date': '2020-01-04', 'color': 'blue', 'users': 98},
        {'date': '2020-01-02', 'color': 'red', 'users': 100},
        {'date': '2020-01-03', 'color': 'red', 'users': 107},
        {'date': '2020-01-04', 'color': 'red', 'users': 114},
        {'date': '2020-01-05', 'color': 'red', 'users': 150},
    ]
```

So far, I know I can get the min date for each color using the code below, but not sure what to do next

```
grouped = df.groupby('color')['date']
min = grouped.min()
```

Answer (score 3):

`sort` the values of the dataframe on `Date` then `groupby` on `color` and transform the column `users` using `first`, then use `Series.div` to divide `users` by this transformed column to get the ratio:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['ratio'] = df['users'].div(
    df.sort_values('date').groupby('color')['users'].transform('first')
)
```

---

```
        date color  users  ratio
0 2020-01-01  blue    100   1.00
1 2020-01-02  blue    102   1.02
2 2020-01-03  blue    104   1.04
3 2020-01-04  blue     98   0.98
4 2020-01-02   red    100   1.00
5 2020-01-03   red    107   1.07
6 2020-01-04   red    114   1.14
7 2020-01-05   red    150   1.50
```